# What is this square bracket syntax and Dict, Callable in python?and these

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was going through Kaggle environments code. [This](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-environments/blob/24a2cea763fe5d68a9f0f4c90b66d13801650316/kaggle_environments/helpers.py#L90) line is:

```
def group_by(items: Iterable[TItem], selector: Callable[[TItem], THash]) -> Dict[THash, List[TItem]]:
```

What are `Iterable`, `Callable` and `Dict`? Are these classes (especially due to capitalized first letter) defined by Python? Also what is this square bracket syntax? Is it something like generics in Java?

Comment: Those are type hints. [You can read more about them here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: those are type hints